# Using MATLAB to save a montage of many images as one large image file at full resolution

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, registration, resolution

I am trying to save a montage of many (~500, 2MB each) images using MATLAB function imwrite, however I keep getting this error:

```
Error using imwrite>validateSizes (line 632)
Images must contain fewer than 2^32 - 1 bytes of data.
Error in imwrite (line 463)
validateSizes(data);
```

here is the code I am working with:

```
close all
clear all
clc
tic
file = 'ImageRegistrations.txt';
info = importdata(file);
ImageNames = info.textdata(:,1);
xoffset = info.data(:,1);
yoffset = info.data(:,2);
for i = 1:length(ImageNames);
ImageNames{i,1} = imread(ImageNames{i,1});
ImageNames{i,1} = flipud(ImageNames{i,1});
end
ImageNames = flipud(ImageNames);

for i=1:length(ImageNames)
    diffx(i) = xoffset(length(ImageNames),1) - xoffset(i,1);
end
diffx = (diffx)';
diffx = flipud(diffx);

for j=1:length(ImageNames)
    diffy(j) = yoffset(length(ImageNames),1) - yoffset(j,1);
end
diffy = (diffy)';
diffy = flipud(diffy);
matrix = zeros(max(diffy)+abs(min(diffy))+(2*1004),max(diffx)+abs(min(diffx))+(2*1002));
%matrix(1:size(ImageNames{1,1},1),1:size(ImageNames{1,1},2)) = ImageNames{1,1};
for q=1:length(ImageNames)
matrix((diffy(q)+abs(min(diffy))+1):(diffy(q)+abs(min(diffy))+size(ImageNames{q,1},1)),(diffx(q)+abs(min(diffx))+1):((diffx(q)+abs(min(diffx))+size(ImageNames{q,1},2)))) = ImageNames{q,1};
end

graymatrix = mat2gray(matrix);
graymatrix = flipud(graymatrix);
figure(2)
imshow(graymatrix)
imwrite(graymatrix, 'montage.tif')
toc
```

I use imwrite because it perserves the final montage in a full resolution file, whereas if I simply click save on the figure file it saves it as a low resolution file.

thanks!

Comment: The [tag: processing] tag should only be used for questions about the Processing language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error does what it says on the tin, really. There is some sort of inbuilt limitation to input variable size in `imwrite`, and you're going over it.

Note that most images are stored as `uint8` but I would guess that you end up with doubles as a result of your processing. That increases the memory usage.

It may be, therefore, that casting to another type would help. Try using `im2uint8` (presuming your variable `graymatrix` is double, scaled between 0 and 1), before calling `imwrite`.