# saving a very large image in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, save

I know that this question has been asked before. But, I could not find a clear answer for it. I have data for a very high resolution colorful image with the size of 50,000 by 60,000 with the data type unit8. I cannot save the entire image by using imwrite. I have gotten the error that says:

"Images must contain fewer than 2^32 - 1 bytes of data"

Is there a way to save the entire image in MATLAB?
right now, I have to  break the data into smaller pieces (sub-images) and then use imwrite to write each piece to a png file. The output format of the file is not important.

Answer (score 0):

Your image occupies 8*50000*60000*3 = 7.2000e+10 bytes of data that is 16.7638 times more than MATLAB image size limit. Why no to split it in 20 pieces, save them and then merge them manually? If you split your image into 6 8x50000x3000x3 pieces, they would all fit into 2^32 limit.

I am sure OP has enough aptitude to do this, but I'll explain the procedure anyway. Convert your image into 50000x60000x3 array and do the following:

```
x = 0:3000:60000;
for i = 1:length(x)-1
   imwrite(A(:,x(i)+1:x(i+1),:),strcat('image',num2str(i),'.png'),'png');
end
```

This would create 20 images for you with names 'image1.png', 'image2.png' and so on. Then, you can merge these images manually using [this first google search result](http://www.photojoiner.net). Perhaps, there is some fancier way to do this, but I think this is the easiest one.

Comment: This is the way that I am doing it, right now. I merge sub-images in adobe photoshop. I thought there might be a way that I do not have to use any other software to merge the images.

Comment: I am not sure whether OpenCV can solve the problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31054105/using-matlab-to-save-a-montage-of-many-images-as-one-large-image-file-at-full-re) has an answer which worked for me: if your image is stored as a double matrix, convert to uint8 with `im2uint8(img)`, then save.